write(self, data: Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
Я пытаюсь запустить следующий код из документации:
from PyQt5 import QtCore

buff = QtCore.QBuffer()
buff.open(QtCore.QBuffer.ReadWrite)
buff.write("Qt rocks!")
buff.seek(0)
buff.getChar(buff.char) # ch == 'Q'
buff.getChar() # ch == 't'
buff.getChar() # ch == ' '
buff.getChar() # ch == 'r'

выдаёт ошибку: write(self, data: Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
Пытался преобразовать строку в массив байтов, но тоже ничего не получилось...

Как именно пробовали?

просто превращал строку в QByteArray

Для данного случая - просто добавьте b перед строкой: b"Qt rocks!". А в целом, если из переменной берется или кириллица используется - делайте encode: "Какой-то текст".encode("utf-8") (вероятно, Qt поддерживает utf-8, но это не точно).

ааа... Спасибо!

Вообще стек-трейс ошибки нужно приводить полностью, без этого непонятно, к какому месту кода ошибка относится. Там каждая строка вывода может быть важна. Хотя тут понятно, если приглядеться, но лучше всё-таки целиком.

Метод getChar не принимает аргументы.
